# Returning and populating jintArray from jni

Tags: c++, arrays, java-native-interface, jint

I'm trying to return a jintArray from C++ to Java but no matter what I do the call keeps hanging and the code just stops. Even with something simple like this

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_main_getIntArray(JNIEnv *env, jclass c) {
        jintArray intArray = env->NewIntArray(5);
        jint values[5] = {69, 69, 69, 69, 69};

        env->SetIntArrayRegion(intArray, 0, 5, values);
        env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(intArray, values, NULL);
        return intArray;
    }
```

In java I'm doing

```
System.out.println("Start getting array");
System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(getIntArray()));
System.out.println("Done getting array");
```

but the only output I get is

> Start getting array

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

- I tried creating a pointer from values[] and using that one in the SetIntArrayRegion
- I tried populating the array myself by looping over it
- I tried removing the ReleaseIntArrayElements

Comment: `ReleaseIntArrayElements` shouldn't be there, since you're not calling `GetIntArrayElements`.

Comment: Just for clarity, since your code doesn't show it: your function is somehow wrapped in an `extern "C"`? (I assume it is, or you should get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` or something of the sort)

Comment: @zenzelezz: Yes, the header file is wrapped into an extern "C". Even without **ReleaseIntArrayElements** the application hangs

Comment: First, check that your native method is ever called. Start commenting out all its body, returning **null**. Then, uncomment contents one line at a time. Maybe, you can add some printf to check what happens inside the native method.

Comment: When dealing with this type of issue I often put a print statement (use cerr if C++, fprintf(stderr) if C) in the C/C++ code after every statement. Not very elegant, but it will pinpoint to the exact line where you code gives you problems, and you get an answer quickly.